# What was Vax'ildan's first encounter with The Hags?

Tags: critical-role

In Episode 20 "Trial of the Take Part 3" of Critical Role, Vax'ildan meets a hag who he's met before. They have a cryptic conversation about "the last time they met," but I'm 99.9% certain that was before the broadcast started.

How did Vax'ildan meet Forsythia and Trista, and how are their fates entwined?

Answer (score 1):

Vox Machina encountered Trysta pre-steam, as illustrated in "The Story of Vox Machina" here:

> "On their way out of the basement, half of the party falls into a trap, tumbling into a cistern and are flushed deep below into a subterranean river system. The trapped party members-Vex, Keyleth, Grog, Tiberius, and Percy- come to rest on a small island in the vast Crystalfen Lake" ... "Barely escaping, they eventually discover the base remnants of an ancient town, long toppled, and a small hut that contains a clever hag named Trysta." - [crtranscript.tumblr.com/story](http://crtranscript.tumblr.com/story)

Note, however, that Vax and Pike were not with the adventurers at the time, having been separated from the party.  It is Keyleth who mistakes Forscythia for Trysta.  It can be assumed that the encounter was relayed to the missing members at some point.

It may be that there was another encounter that was not captured in the available material though.

Comment: A lot of us are on SFF while at work and are unable to watch videos. It would be helpful if you provided a summary of the video and how it applies to your answer so that we don't have to watch it to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: my apologies - from the Critical Role Transcript: "On their way out of the basement, half of the party falls into a trap, tumbling into a cistern and are flushed deep below into a subterranean river system. The trapped party members-Vex, Keyleth, Grog, Tiberius, and Percy- come to rest on a small island in the vast Crystalfen Lake" ... "Barely escaping, they eventually discover the base remnants of an ancient town, long toppled, and a small hut that contains a clever hag named Trysta."  https://crtranscript.tumblr.com/story

Comment: Good start. Could you [edit] that into your answer? Comments have a tendency to disappear.